# SQL_ERROR: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs' threw an exception

Tags: c#, mysql, mono

I have an error with my C# code and MySQL.
Can you help me solve it please ?

Here is my code :

```
try
{
     using (MySqlConnection dbcon = new MySqlConnection(SQLConnectionString))
     {
         dbcon.Open(); // ERROR HERE
         string sql = "SELECT * FROM scp_patreons";
         MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
         command = dbcon.CreateCommand();
         command.CommandText = sql;
         using (MySqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
         {
             while (dr.Read())
             {
                 string fullname = (string)dr["fullname"];
                 plugin.Info("Name: " + fullname + "");
             }
         }
     }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     plugin.Info("SQL_ERROR: " + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
 }


string SQLConnectionString = "Server=*; Database=*; User ID = *; Password=*; Pooling=false;SslMode=None;";
```

and i'm getting the error :

```
SQL_ERROR: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs' threw an exception.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_generic_class_init(intptr)
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SetConnectAttrs () [0x00018] in <699dc28794d34867bd2008187eb8039c>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate (System.Boolean reset) [0x00080] in <699dc28794d34867bd2008187eb8039c>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate (System.String authMethod, System.Boolean reset) [0x0002a] in <699dc28794d34867bd2008187eb8039c>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open () [0x0033f] in <699dc28794d34867bd2008187eb8039c>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open () [0x0000e] in <699dc28794d34867bd2008187eb8039c>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) [0x0004e] in <699dc28794d34867bd2008187eb8039c>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open () [0x0016d] in <699dc28794d34867bd2008187eb8039c>:0 
  at PlayerXP.PlayerXP.OnEnable () [0x00021] in <80e302c4eac64aeebd42276ff4a14839>:0
```

I'm running 5.7.25 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Server : Localhost with UNIX socket
Protocol version : 10
User : root@localhost
Server char : UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
Mono JIT compiler version 5.18.0.268
Connector/NET 8.0.15
I use Debian 9.6.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT :

The new error message :

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs..cctor () [0x0000f] in <699dc28794d34867bd2008187eb8039c>:0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_generic_class_init(intptr)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SetConnectAttrs () [0x00018] in <699dc28794d34867bd2008187eb8039c>:0
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate (System.Boolean reset) [0x00080] in <699dc28794d34867bd2008187eb8039c>:0
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate (System.String authMethod, System.Boolean reset) [0x0002a] in <699dc28794d34867bd2008187eb8039c>:0
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open () [0x0033f] in <699dc28794d34867bd2008187eb8039c>:0
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open () [0x0000e] in <699dc28794d34867bd2008187eb8039c>:0
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) [0x0004e] in <699dc28794d34867bd2008187eb8039c>:0
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open () [0x0016d] in <699dc28794d34867bd2008187eb8039c>:0
at PlayerXP.PlayerXP.OnEnable () [0x00021] in <cc464d994e5a47c88df91f25374d2f29>:0
```

Comment: Wrong password?

Comment: No @TheImpaler it's the right password.

Comment: never do "SQL_ERROR: " + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace. Do ex.ToString() instead and see if you can get some useful info

Comment: Ok @Steve I modified my post with new error message.

Comment: It's possible that Connector/NET isn't 100% compatible with Mono. Try https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ an OSS alternative with better cross-platform support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [@Bradley Grainger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23633/bradley-grainger), my problem is solved. I have tried http://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector and it works !