# C# Connecting to MySql DB through android device

Tags: c#, android, mysql, database, xamarin.forms

I've just working with c# and mysql and have ran into a problem. I've created a mysql db(remote access) using mysql workbench. I've been using visual studio to write the code(c#), xamarin.forms. The aim is to connect the database on multiple platforms. I'm trying to make it connect through windows(uwp) and android, it works fine on the windows(uwp). However when I try and run it through my android device to test the app I get an error. The error states "SYSTEM.TYPEINITIALIZATIONEXCEPTION......OPERATION IS NOT SUPPORTED ON THIS PLATFORM". Any idea on how to get around this? Thank you.

This is the code:

'''

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
namespace demo {
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs a)
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(user id; password);
            try
            {

                con.Open();
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    ((Button)sender).Text = $"Connected";
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ((Button)sender).Text = ex.ToString();
            }
            con.Close();


        }




    }


}
```

Comment: we can't debug code that we can't see

Comment: Ah totally forgot, added it now

Comment: IMO we should not be connecting to DB directly form app. Instead call web api and let api do all work. This would reduce complexity on UI and make it lightweight.

Comment: Which ADO.NET provider are you using?  MySql.Data? MySqlConnector? What happens if you switch?

Comment: Im using MySql.Data, whats the difference between the two? Could it solve this?

Comment: @Harv MySqlConnector has fewer dependencies and may be more compatible with a non-.NET-Framework platform, such as Xamarin.

Comment: See also these existing answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50354463/23633 https://stackoverflow.com/a/55479213/23633

Comment: Hey guys, Im getting a different error now on my android device when I try and run my app, I've added MySqlConnector as a reference in vs, the error is now : MYSQL.DATA.MYSQLCLIENT.MYSQLEXCEPTION: UNABLE TO CONNECT TO ANY OF THE SPECIFIED MYSQL HOSTS. .......

Comment: I've tried to do the same thing but this time I've used a online server from db4free.net, anyone know how comes it works with this on the android device but not with a mysql db which has been given remote access?