# Problem with Connecting to AWS RDS MySQL Database with Xamarin Forms App (C#, Android Emulator)

Tags: c#, android, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Hi stackoverflow community,

I am trying my hands on some Xamarin Forms to code my own app. Together with that I want to expand my knowledge about AWS RDS.
While Coding a Database class in C# that should return a value from my Database as a DisplayAlert() (on Android Emulator) I ran into an exception."System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception.'"
It worked on Windows Forms.

My Code:

````
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace StudyWithMe
{
    class DB
    {
        public static MySqlConnection dbConnection;
        static string host = "awsEndpoint";
        static string id = "myuserid";
        static string pwd = "mypassword";
        static string database = "mydatabase";
        static string port = "3306";

        public string getSalt(string email)
        {
            OpenSql();
            string query = "SELECT salt";
            query += " FROM Authentication WHERE email = '" + email + "';";
            string salt = ExecuteQuery(query).Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
            Close();
            return salt;
        }

        private static void OpenSql()
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = string.Format("Server = {0};port={4}; Database = {1}; Uid = {2}; Pwd = {3};", host, database, id, pwd, port);
                MySqlConnection dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                dbConnection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw new Exception("error" + e.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
        private void Close()
        {

            if (dbConnection != null)
            {
                dbConnection.Close();
                dbConnection.Dispose();
                dbConnection = null;
            }

        }

        private static DataSet ExecuteQuery(string sqlString)
        {
            if (dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                try
                {

                    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlString, dbConnection);
                    da.Fill(ds);

                }
                catch (Exception ee)
                {
                    throw new Exception("SQL:" + sqlString + "/n" + ee.Message.ToString());
                }
                return ds;
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}```

Thanks for your help!
PS: I did install the NuGet package MySql.Data
````

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/56740864/23633, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55479213/23633, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50354463/23633.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the `MySql.Data` NuGet package and install [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) instead; it has better cross-platform compatibility with Xamarin.

FWIW, initiating a database connection from an Android device is a bad idea, because the credentials are easily extracted from the application and could be used by anyone to log into your database. The better approach is for the Xamarin app to authenticate against a web service (that you author), e.g., with username and password, and for the web service to connect to the database.

Comment: Also called REST

Comment: Thanks!! I will keep that in mind. How would I go about making my own web service?