# System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException upon attempting to log in to .NETCore application with MySqlClient

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm building an contact manager application using .Net 5.0 in Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. I am using MySql Connector (MySql.Data.dll) to connect to MySql database. The connection works, though only after adding the older version (6.1.2) - it is possible to insert data to the database. However, upon searching through the database (logging in or verifying whether the username already exists - here the error is more specific, listed below) I am receiving such an error:

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: „The given key
> 'utf8mb4' was not present in the dictionary.”

Here is my connection string:

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost; port=3307; username=root; " +
            "password=; database=csharp_contact_manager_db; CharSet=utf8;");
```

Here's my code for logging in functionality:

```
Database db = new Database();

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `username` = @un AND `password` = @pass", db.getConnection);

            command.Parameters.Add("@un", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxUsername.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxPassword.Text;

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            adapter.Fill(table);
```

The aforementioned error always occurs for adapter.Fill(table) line.

Here's the query I'm using for verifying whether the username already exists in the database:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM 'user' WHERE 'username'=@un";
```

In case of the above verification, this is an error I'm receiving:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: „You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
> version for the right syntax to use near ''user' WHERE
> 'username'='user'' at line 1”

I downgraded the MySql.Data.dll version, since this is what I've receiving so far when attempting to connect to the database with the version of 8.0.17:

> System.TypeInitializationException: „The type initializer for
> 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs' threw an exception.”
>
> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file
> specified.

I've already seen similar posts regarding this, none of the suggested solutions helped in my case though.

Cheers,
Filip

Comment: What's the full stack trace?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you're asking about

Comment: Can you replace the * with actual column names and check any of the columns are returning NULL.  Besides that, the version you are using may have a known bug regarding the same.

Perhaps you can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/

Comment: That was one of the suggested solutions I've seen so far. Perhaps this is the best possible way for that. However, I am unsure how to convert it. As when I was using MySqlConnector, this object: 
"MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, db.getConnection)" did not accept strings. 
As for the null columns, none of them are returning NULL from what I've checked, the error is still the same :(

Comment: The `MySqlConnectAttrs` exception likely indicates that MySql.Data isn't compatible with your .NET runtime; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55479213/23633. I would recommend switching to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ which has better .NET Core compatibility.

Comment: @Filip MySqlConnector's MySqlCommand has a constructor that takes `string, MySqlConnection`: https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlcommand/mysqlcommand/. Do you need to use `new MySqlCommand(query, db.getConnection())`?

Comment: Nah, not really. Just wanted to avoid too much changes but since the issue seems not to be 'fixable', I just might adjust it. Thank you for your help @BradleyGrainger

Comment: And @RajeeshMadambat